# How to know the occurrence of a text in row of data frame pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

```
     C1    
0   John   
1   John  
2   John 
3   Michale
4   Michale
5   Newton
6   Newton 
7   John
8   John
9   John
```

I want to know how many time John occurred row wise. Suppose John occurred from 0 to 2 In result i want from 0 to 2 John. from 3 to 4 Michel from 5 to 6 Newton

Result I want in this format:

```
Start  End   Name   
0      2     John  
3      4     Michale
5      6     newton
7      9     John
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zero: Would adding the below to your code help ..?? :)

```
df_new = df.reset_index().groupby('C1')['index'].agg(['min', 'max']).rename(
        columns={'min': 'start', 'max': 'end'})

df_new.reset_index().rename(columns={'C1':'Name'})
```

Edit: Maybe something like this..? I am still learning but there is no harm trying. :)

```
labels = (df.C1 != df.C1.shift()).cumsum()
df1 = pd.concat([df,labels],axis = 1,names = 'label')
df1.columns = ['C1','label']
df_new = df1.reset_index().groupby(['label','C1']).agg(['min', 'max']).rename(
    columns={'min': 'start', 'max': 'end'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'C1':'Name'})
df_new
```

Comment: This is a copy of Zero's answer

Comment: yes, i am glad to give it to @zero. it was just a suggestion.Any way to make it accepted..?? :) I was one of the upvoters for that ans too..

Comment: you can request the OP to do the same if you like :)

Comment: @A.Yadav : The previous answer is the original answer, this addition was a suggestion. Could you please make it an accepted answer? Thank you. :)

Comment: its okay zero has enough reputation anyways :P

Comment: @Zero I made a change in my question can you please help me with that ...In previous one when I am doing repetition  it was giving min and max index value

Comment: @anky_91 both are not acceptable as per my requirement If I could ask in this way(edited) this solution won''t work.

Comment: @A.Yadav : I tried something similar. Maybe this could help..??? pl check edited ans

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
In [163]: df.reset_index().groupby('C1')['index'].agg(['min', 'max']).rename(
            columns={'min': 'start', 'max': 'end'})
Out[163]:
         start  end
C1
John         0    2
Michale      3    4
Newton       5    6
```

Comment: Yea, what do we do now? :-)

Comment: sorry about that @Zero I have requested the OP to change the accepted ans. Lets hope. :)